# CUDA header inclusion fails, works in .cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, cuda, header

I have a project in Visual Studio 2013 with the CUDA Toolkit 7.5 where inclusion of header files works for `.cpp` files but not for `.cu` files. I have a header file `test.h` and its implementation `test.cu` as well as the `main.cu` file.

The file structure is:

```
projectdir/
    /include
        /test.h
    /src
        /test.cu
        /main.cu
```

In the project properties page, I have the following set up:

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories =
**$(ProjectDir)include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)**

Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Common -> Additional Include Directories =
**$(ProjectDir)include;%(Include)**

`#include "../include/test.h"` compiles, `#include "test.h"` does not compile in the `.cu` files.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/25icHzpg) is a pastebin of the error output.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/EE215SJQ) is a pastebin of the CUDA C/C++ Command Line settings as well as the source code.

Any help to resolve this is greatly appreciated. While the `#include ../include/test.h` lets me run the program it's annoying to not have it work properly.

Comment: Can you see what arguments your .c and .cpp endsup with?

Comment: Can you specify more in detail what you are looking for? Kind of a novice here.

Comment: I'm guessing this is what you're looking for:

Under C/C++ -> Command Line:
`/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"D:\Software\Dropbox\Skola\Master's Courses\DH2323 Computer Graphics and Interaction\Project\CUDA_udacity\CUDA_udacity\include" /I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\CUDA_udacity.pch"`

Comment: Yes, and the same for the other. Then the next job is to compare all the -I statements.

Comment: In your text, you say the implementation of `test.h` is in `test.cu`, but in your section described as "file structure" you list a `test.cpp` not `test.cu`.  What filenames and structures do you actually have?

Comment: And what does "works" and "not work" mean? What error messages is the compiler emitting?

Comment: Exactly.  In the failing case, provide the complete command line generated by VS that calls `nvcc`, as well as the actual error output.

Comment: @RobertCrovella and the rest thanks a lot for the reply. [Here](http://pastebin.com/wUEbEFuV) is a pastebin with the error output. The arguments for the .cu file in CUDA C/C++ options are [here](http://pastebin.com/vg1KjJT4)

Comment: Do you really have a directory with "\CUDA_udacity\CUDA_udacity" in it's path? That looks highly suspicious to me..

Comment: @talonmies Yes I do. The first folder is where i have the .sln file (the VS solution file) and inside the next folder is the .vcxproj  file (the project file) as well as the src and include folders. The "Project" folder is created by me and is related to my school course, under which I have the "CUDA_udacity" folder in which I placed the "CUDA_udacity" visual studio solution. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @RobertCrovella also edited the first post go correctly display test.cu. I should also point out that I changed the main file from cpp to cu as thats required to run kernels. Problem remains though, including headers straight up doesnt work in the .cu files.

Comment: At the moment, your compilation of `main.cu` does not show any errors.  Does `main.cu` also include `test.h`?  Because previously you had indicated that "However in main.ccp, #include "test.h" works but in test.cu only #include ../include/test.h works."

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, the bottom line is that in the .cu files, `#include "test.h"` doesn't compile while `#include "../include/test.h"` does. In .cpp files, both versions do compile. I have the same "Additional Include Directory" in both C/C++ settings and CUDA C/C++ settings, as stated above. Thanks.

Comment: How is it then that the `main.cu` in your pastebin output compiles without error?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry for the confusion, I had `#include "../include/test.h"` in my main.cu which does compile. Changed it to `#include "test.h"` and [here](http://pastebin.com/25icHzpg) is a new pastebin. Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the include path to VC++ options as well. Apparently this is needed for .cu-files but not for .cpp-files.